# Load All Tables in SQLite database into combobox

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlite

I would like to know how to load and display all the tables in the database into a combobox and, if possible, display the table in a listview when it is selected from the combobox.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like something that is already built for what you are asking to do, try downloading SqliteBrowser:

http://sqlitebrowser.org/

This allows you to see all of your tables, view each table individually, and execute SQL statements.

Comment: I have that already. In what way would it provide VB.NET sample code of what Im trying to achieve? 
I not concerned about the SQL statement, Iam concerned about the VB.NET syntax that can loadup the tables into combobox and display it into a listview.
Stackoverflow isnt being helpful at all. Nearly all questions Ive asked have never had good responses unlike other sites. it feels like full of snubs (no pun intended). thanx anyways

Comment: I gave you an answer based on the problem you described.  I am sorry it was not helpful to you.  It sounded to me like you were looking to build something that already existed.

Comment: ok. sorry too. i didnt know you didnt get my point too well. Anyways, i grateful for your help. I have found some resources at Kirupa through my search on google and its quite helpful. thank you.